# How to debug Javascript code of web application on Chrome browser installed on Ipad

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ipad, ghostlab

I have a questions how to debug javascript code of web application in Chrome browser on Ipad? The problem is that Ipad's Chrome has no Developers Tools, so there is no way to debug Javascript there.

I read something here, but there are no details on my problems.

https://css-tricks.com/using-chrome-devtools-to-debug-javascript-in-any-browser-with-ghostlab-2/

UPDATE1: 
I found that there is application called GhostLab for debugging remotely web browsers on ipad. But my questions are:

1. Can I debug Chrome with it?
2. Can I use windows' GhostLab to debug Chrome on IPad?

Comment: The best ive seen so far is Weinre. It allows console execution but not step debugging. As far as I know, no product provides step debugging.

Comment: Can I use it on windows machine ..or only MAC OS? Is it possible JS or only HTML and CSS?

Comment: It will run anywhere nodejs will run. I have personally only used it on windows and can confirm it works. It mimics most of the features of the chrome dev tools with notable exception of the 'source' tab. However, you can run arbitrary javascript in the 'console' it provides. [Weinre User Interface](https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/UserInterface.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way where you can use the developer tool of chrome on Ipad.

but the preferred way to debug on Ipad is using

[Remote Debugging with Safari Web Inspector](http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I need additional Apple computer to debug it right?

Comment: @P.K. Right! you may try to use emulators